# How do I know when a face has left the scene?

Tags: ios, arkit, object-recognition

I'm using ARKit with the `ARFaceTrackingConfiguration`.  It detects my face when I look at the camera, which is great.  However, when I move out of view of the camera, I don't get `renderer:didRemoveNode:forAnchor:`.

What I would like to do is detect when the face has gone so that I can reset the session and begin looking for a (potentially) new face.

Edit: Seems I can do something like this:

```
- (void)renderer:(id<SCNSceneRenderer>)renderer updateAtTime:(NSTimeInterval)time {
  SCNVector3 location = [renderer projectPoint:self.faceNode.position];
  CGPoint point = CGPointMake(round(location.x), round(location.y));
  BOOL isNodeVisible = CGRectContainsPoint(self.view.frame, point);
  // ... do stuff ...
}
```

Though I'm not sure that's the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an `iPhoneX`so can't test this exactly.

But I believe you can use `isNodeInsideFrustum:withPointOfView` method which:

> Returns a Boolean value indicating whether a node might be visible from a specified point of view.

In a simple test I create an `SCNNode` which I have called `faceNode`.

Then using the delegate callback:

`renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval)`

I was able to determine if the node was in view of the camera e.g:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {

        if let currentPointOfView = augmentedRealityView?.pointOfView{

            let faceIsVisible = augmentedRealityView.isNode(faceNode, insideFrustumOf: currentPointOfView)

            if faceIsVisible{
                print("Face Is In View Of The Camera")
            }else{
                print("Face Is Not In View Of The Camera")

            }

      }
}
```

Hopefully this will help in your current situation....

Comment: I will give this a shot.  Thanks.

Comment: Hm, doesn't exactly work.  `sNode(_, insideFrustrumOf)` does return false when I turn the phone away but then it returns true again.  And then it just seems randomly to flip between true and false.